# Chef - knife solo cook fails with an rsync error

Tags: chef-infra, knife

`knife solo prepare username@my-ip-address -p 4111` completes successfully but when running the same with `cook`, the provisioning fails with an rsync error:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
ERROR: RuntimeError: Failed to launch command ["rsync", "-rL", "--rsh=ssh username@my-ip-address -p 4111 -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/home/my_username/.chef/knife-solo-sockets/%h -o ControlPersist=3600", "--delete-after", "-zt", "--exclude=revision-deploys", "--exclude=.git", "--exclude=.hg", "--exclude=.svn", "--exclude=.bzr", "/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/knife-solo-0.5.1/lib/knife-solo/resources/patch_cookbooks/", ":~/chef-solo/cookbooks-1"]
```

My host machine is an ubuntu desktop 15.10 and my node is an ubuntu server 14.04LTS.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on IRC, that error means password-less SSH isn't working. Most likely you don't have your SSH keys set up correctly, but try running SSH manually to see the specifics.